# Facebook Submit for Login Review message

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I have started seeing a **"Submit for Login Review -- Some of the permissions below have not been approved for use by Facebook"** message show all my most recent app's login screen when clicking the Facebook login.

It does not prevent the login process and does not say what permissions have not been approved. I only have public profile and email (which are auto granted.) The Facebook app itself is not requiring or requesting verification (that I can see.)

My app uses ASP.NET Identity, but that has not changed and my older Facebook apps are working.

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have to request Advanced Access for email. When I do this, the message goes away. When I look at older Facebook Apps, this is already set.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).